# Установка компонент Android в Qt

Tags: qt5, android-sdk, android-ndk

При настройке в Qt Android окружения запрашивается установка неустановленных пакетов.

Выдается следующее сообщение:
"Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462: На устройстве не осталось свободного места."

Свободного места на диске полно (около 600 Гб)

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Помогло расширение tnpfs (/tmp)
вопрос закрыт